# How to "hide" not "exclude" quick filter selection

Tags: filter, set, tableau-api

I need help for selection in quick filters.
When I search how to keep only the value we want to show in quick filters, some source guide how to do it by sets, also another way to do it is by create a duplicate calculated field.

Let's say i have 4 selection in my workbook.

1. Grade A
2. Grade B
3. Grade C
4. Null

and they are one in a calculated field named "Grade"

I need to show only "Grade A" and "Grade B". So i made create a set that only contain "Grade A" and "Grade B", let say i called it "Grade - Sets". When the "Grade" variable already on the quick filters, I also put "Grade - Sets" into the filter box. The selection of "Grade" is down into only "Grade A" and "Grade B", however in my workbook it's means that "Grade C" and "Null" are "excluded" from the workbook not "hide". Which means it's affect the calculation, while I want to show the calculation of all Grades but only show "Grade A" and "Grade B" as thr quick filters.

Am I do it wrong? or is there another way to look at it?

Thanks

Randy

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have used in the past involves creating a calculated field and using it to modify your filter.

Try creating a calculated field with the formula down below.

(You can name this calculated field [Grades(Reduced)] or something to that effect)

```
IF [Grade] = "Grade A" OR
 [Grade] = "Grade B" OR
 [Grade] = "Other Grades you may want to include, etc..."
THEN [Grade]
ELSE "DO NOT INCLUDE"
END
```

What you do then is exclude the "DO NOT INCLUDE" value with the [Grades(Reduced)] filter and add a Quick Filter for the [Grade] and select the option to show *Only Relevant Values*.

This should effectively hide certain quick field selections without excluding them from the calculations.

There are also ways to go about this by creating groups, but this is my go to method.

Let me know if it works for you!

-Dima